# Pseudoinverse of large sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, svd, sparse

I am trying to calculate the pseudoinverse of a large sparse matrix in R using the singular value decomposition. The matrix is roughly 240,000 x 240,000, and I have it stored as type `dgCMatrix`. I have tried using `pinv`, `ginv`, and other standard pseudoinverse functions, but they error out due to memory constraints. I then tried to opt for the sparse matrix svd provided by the package `irlba`, which I was then going to use to compute the pseudoinverse using the standard formula after converting all outputs to sparse matrices. My code is here:

```
lim = 40
digits = 4
SVD =irlba(L,lim)
tU = round(SVD$u,digits)
nonZeroU = which(abs(U)>0,arr.ind = T)
sparseU = sparseMatrix(i=nonZeroU[,2],j=nonZeroU[,1],x = U[nonZeroU])
V = round(SVD$v,digits)
nonZeroV = which(abs(V)>0,arr.ind = T)
sparseV = sparseMatrix(i=nonZeroV[,1],j=nonZeroV[,2],x = U[nonZeroV])
D = as(Diagonal(x=1/SVD$d),"sparseMatrx")
pL =D%*%sparseU
pL = sparseV%*%pL
```

I am able to get to the last line without an issue, but then I get an error due to memory constraints that says

```
Error in sparseV %*% pL : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

Of course I could piece together the pseudoinverse entry by entry using a for loop and vector multiplications, but I would like to be able to calculate it using a simple function that takes advantage of the sparsity of the resultant pseudoinverse matrix. Due to the nature of the original matrix (it is a graph laplacian), I know that the pseudoinverse should also be a sparse matrix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. What is the type of the `pL` matrix (and its dimensions)? 2. How much RAM do you have available generally? 3. How sparse are we talking? <1%? <5%? 5-10%? 10%+ (so not really).  4. I hope you notice that you are doing a *dense* calculation so I somewhat suspect that you try to evaluate a 240k-by-240k dense matrix as a final result. Are you sure that `diag(1/SVD$d)` is a sparse matrix? 5. Maybe you want to try a smaller problem first, say that all variable types are as expected and then try to throw in *and the kitchen-sink*. (+1 fun problem)

Comment: Seems like a use-case for solving the problem with power iteration + Gram-Schmidt, both of which can be done to use sparse matrix multiplication. (+1)

Comment: @usεr11852 I am working with 16 gb of ram, and the type of pL is inherited from the type of the type of sparseU, which is dgCMatrix. The matrix L has only 400,000 entries, so it is extremely sparse-- <1%. D has dimensions 40x40 because I only took the first 40 singular values. The reason I thought it should be doable is that if the svd can be taken, I would have thought this should be roughly the same complexity problem...

Comment: ( By matrix `L`I guess you mean `pL` right? ) `D` doesn't seem to come into play here. Are you sure that `pL` is not `dgeMatrix`?

Comment: Try ensuring that `diag(1/SVD$d)` is a `ddiMatrix` before multiplying with `sparseU`.

Comment: You will need over 900 GB Ram to store the results (potentially half that if your matrix is symmetric), because the orthogonal matrices in the SVD are almost surely not going to be sparse.  Even if you're sure they won't be, then (1) floating point roundoff error very well might make them non-sparse and (2) you would need to use some kind of special algorithm that "knows" the results will be sparse.

Comment: @whuber: Yeah, That's why I mentioned ensuring that `diag(1/SVD$d)` is a `ddiMatrix` as to ensure that "sparse" type are ensure. It is a (unfortunate?) fact of matrix life that sparse matrices usually do not have sparse inverses but as the OP is working with graph Laplacians maybe he has some expert knowledge on the matter. In any case as I mentioned originally, one should first try a smaller problem and see how things are developing and then try the full on problem.

Comment: @usεr11852  you're right there was a typo -- I edited the post so that D is actually being used (no change it the result). By L mean the original matrix that was decomposed using SVD. And pL is indeed a dgCMatrix. D was a dsCMatrix before, so I changed it to be a ddiMatrix (edited code accordingly) -- with no effect

Comment: @whuber thank you for your helpful comments. First I will compute the pseudoinverse with brute force (replacing space with time -- probably a lot of time ...). Then if it turns out to be sparse I will consider how this could be exploited

Comment: Should this be moved to stack overflow or mathematics?

Comment: Either [SO] or [cs.SE]: why not pick one and flag this post for migration?

Comment: Don't pick neither; (Stack Overflow or Computer Science). Go for the Computational Science SE.